# How can I pass data from a .Net Web Application to my Java Applet

Tags: c#, java, .net

How can I pass and recover an ID from my .Net Web Application to my Java Applet that runs in this Web Application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by serializing / deserializing  the data, just a thought. :)

Answer (score 1):

Theres a few ways to do this...

- Use a API to pass information back and forward (for example SOAP or REST) you can then provide the user with a "Token" to pass between the two applications using the QueryString for the servers to use as a primary key to fetch the data.
- Use the query string to directly pass the information
- (Less reliable) Use a cookie if the two applications are on the same domain
- Use a common datastore (ie database, memcached etc etc depending on what your trying to pass)

Each have their advantages and disadvantages. What type of data are you trying to pass and is the user involved in the transaction?

Comment: Well, I need pass just an ID. Is a Integer. In my .Net application I has a Java Applet but I need to pass to this java applet my ID. What the best option ?